# Deploying to http://localhost/ReportServer Error rsAccessDenied - only from with in VS2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

Righ-clk -> deploy rdl file from within VS2017 results in error:

```
Deploying to http://localhost/ReportServer Error rsAccessDenied
The permissions granted to user 'xxx\xxx' are insufficient for performing this operation.
```

However from IE, I can load http://localhost/ReportServer or http://localhost/Reports and also granted all roles.

Also from IE, I can upload the same exact rdl successfully.

Any ideas on the issue using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Solution : Just like IE, run Visual Studio as local Administrator. Then you can deploy from within VS.